# What exactly do we mean by rendering in react js?

Tags: reactjs, dom, render, virtual-dom

Can somebody please take away my confusion about react rendering process?
when we update the state and the browser re-paint the UI of the updated component.  is that what we call rendering? or when the virtual dom informs the real DOM (browser dom) of the changes?

Comment: The very first google result on "what is rendering in react" would give you an answer